# My elliptical cycle is too easy for me... I don't want to throw it away. What can I do with it?

Tags: workout, cardio, elliptical

I bought an elliptical cycle to lose weight. After losing some weight and getting used to it now it feels as easy as walking. It is basically useless now. But I don't want it to go to waste. So I'm looking for a way to make it useful for my workout.

Can I increase its resistance by modifying it somehow?

Would wearing a 40lbs rucksack while using it a good idea?

PS: [This](http://www.hepsiburada.com/dynamic-e16-eliptik-bisiklet-pm-spor1dybse16) is the cycle I have.  It has 11-pound magnetic flywheel, which is why it is so easy I think.

Comment: Have you tried interval training?

Comment: http://www.popsugar.com/fitness/How-Make-Elliptical-Harder-25764226 has some suggestions, but the ones for the incline don't seem applicable to you and I'm a bit skeptical about them claiming to target belly fat. But as rrirower said, intervals might work for you. Is it possible to do the exercise faster or does it gave a governor to limit your speed?

Comment: I'm already going relatively fast. When I go very fast (for interval training), It feels like I'm a ballet dancer and as if I'm just sitting on air without a chair. I doubt that is useful or anatomically a good idea, because of the limitations of elliptical. What do you think?

Comment: just an idea, you may add extra weight to the steps which may make it difficult to perform.

Comment: Have you tried HIIT? I have alternated using HIIT between the elliptical and mini-trampoline and loved it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with elliptical machines for cardio training. My leg muscles became very used to the movement so it became hard for me increase my heart rate. I realized that there are two points of power to make the elliptical spin: from your legs pushing on the pedals, and from your arms pushing and pulling on the handles. I was very dominant with my legs so I tried to focus more energy on pulling and pushing from the arm handles. This definitely changed the dynamics for endurance resulting in my heart rate jumping in a short amount of time which was my goal.

In short, you can adjust the amount of energy you are using from your legs to your arms or vise versa to add difficulty depending on your current strengths.